# Is there a limit for AWS RDS max_connection settings for my instance?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a free tier RDS PostgreSQL database db.t2.micro (1 core, 1 Gib). My architecture did the RDS collapse because it reaches the max number of concurrent connections.

When I query `select * from pg_settings where name='max_connections'`, the result was 87.

I found this formula about the capacity of the `max_connection` attribute for each instance based on the memory:

```
LEAST({DBInstanceClassMemory/9531392},5000)
```

For my instance, the number was 104, and I modified the parameter group to this value, and still my RDS collapse.

I made a last attempt updating the `max_connections` to 500 believing that it'll not work because the limit is 104. But to my surprise the database worked and could handle all the concurrent connections (above 104):

[image]

Obviously, I'm missing something.

Is really there a limit of `max_connections` for my instance?

If I change the `max_connection` setting the pricing for my instance change?

Also, I'm curious about What represents the horizontal line in the graphic, because it is at the level of my initial `max_connection` setting, and before the change, it was not present

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure but I'm interested what you're doing to hit that many connections on a small instance? Are you running against Lambda or something? If so you could use RDS proxy instead!

Comment: @AlexBailey, yeah. My architecture is file to S3 that triggers Lambda -> Lambda parsing file and upload to RDS. I didn't know the RDS proxy service, I'll check out. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! RDS should definitely help there and it's designed exactly for Lambdas which are connecting to RDS instances. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html#RDS_Limits.MaxConnections, you should've hit the limit there.

That said, I guess one of two possible things are happening here:

- AWS do not enforce the limits. I guess they could be suggesting the limits based on instance size here.
- There is some kind of "burst" allowed. Similar to IOPS there could be a small "burst" balance that you can scale to temporarily without affecting service.

Answer (score 0):

The formula is just the **default value** according to AWS, while the Permitted range of values for Postgres is **6–8388607**.

That said, it's unclear why you got 87 (and my t3.micro) has 81 as the max_connections setting. I'm glad that it works to higher connection counts!